# How are Ashtabhairavas related to Kalabhairava?

Tags: shiva, puranas, shiva-purana, bhairava

We know that Kalabhairava was created from Siva's forehead.

> "Mahadeva then created a wonderful person, Bhairava, from the middle of his brows to quell the pride of Brahma. *- Siva Purana Vidyesvara Samhita 8.1*

Also,

> "O sage, on hearing the haughty words of the lotus-born Brahma, Siva became angry as if out for destruction.

> Angrily, he created a Purusa Bhairava blazing in great brilliance. Then he spoke lovingly.

> **O Kalabhairava**, at the outset this lotus-born
> Brahma shall be chastised by you. You shine like the god of death, hence you are Kalaraja.

> You are called Bhairava because you are of terrifying features and you are capable of supporting the universe. Since even Kala is afraid of you, you are called Kalabhairava.

*- Siva Purana, Satarudrasamhita, 8.44-47*

Later, Kalabhairava chopped off Brahma's fifth head.

However, the same Siva Purana also describes Ashtabhairavas (eight Bhairavas, namely Asitāṅga, Ruru, Caṇḍa, Krodha, Unmatta, Kapālī, Bhīṣaṇa, Saṃhāra).

Siva said,

> "O Virabhadra, O Nandin, **O eight Bhairavas**,
> the frontier guards, let the Ganas start along with my sons at my bidding. - *Siva Purana, Rudresvara Samhita, Parvati Khanda, Section III 33.2-3*

Later we can find eight different Tantras for each of these Ashtabhairvas.

My question is, what is the relation between Kalabhairava and Ashtabhairvas.